# IOS / Safari: CSS Content overlapping issue

Tags: css, ios, iphone, safari

Currently a strange content overlapping error for IOS / Safari on an iphone 11. Safari on desktop (With Iphone view) seems to be working fine, so it seems like some kind of issue IOS is causing.

ZIndex is set correctly on all elements. I don't know what else to do. Thanks!

[image]

Here's the code for the page itself. (Notice the zIndex is set, but, in our picture on the right, this entire page is behind the foreground.)

```
<div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
          // alignItems: "center"
        }}
      >
        <div
          style={{
            width: "100vw",
            borderRadius: 5,
            minHeight: "100vh",
            top: 0,
            backgroundColor: "#f5f5f5",
            zIndex: 220,
            opacity: 1,
          }}
        >
          <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
            <div
              style={{
                width: "100%",
                display: "flex",
                flexDirection: "row",
                justifyContent: "flex-end",
              }}
            >
              <img
                id="close"
                onClick={() => this.closeModal()}
                src={Close}
                style={{
                  width: "10vw",
                  height: "10vw",
                  marginTop: 40,
                  marginRight: 40,
                }}
              />
            </div>
            <div
              id="bar"
              style={{
                display: "flex",
                flexDirection: "column",
                justifyContent: "center",
                alignItems: "center",
                paddingTop: 10,
                paddingBottom: 10,
              }}
            >
              {/* <div
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center",
            }}
          >
            Filters
          </div> */}
              <PriceDialogMobile
                minPrice={this.props.minPrice}
                maxPrice={this.props.maxPrice}
                clearContent={() => this.changePrice("$", "$")}
                changePrice={(min, max) => this.changePrice(min, max)}
              />
              <CategoryDialogMobile
                categories={this.props.categories}
                clearContent={() =>
                  this.changeCategory([
                    true,
                    true,
                    true,
                    true,
                    true,
                    true,
                    true,
                    true,
                    true,
                  ])
                }
                changeCategory={(categories) => this.changeCategory(categories)}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: impossible to give tips without any CSS and HTML markup so show us some :)

Comment: @OlSen Added :)

Comment: don't want to guess, what is the framework you run this markup on? react? worth mention in your question what you use to go off standard markup.

Comment: or you copy paste the markup directly out of safari dev environment cause you actually have mainly a css problem. ^^ That way the framework running the markup doesn't interfere much to find the spoiler.